# Difference between @import and link in CSS

Tags: css, import, hyperlink

I'm learning some CSS to tweak my project template. I come to this problem and didn't find a clear answer on the web. Is there a difference between using @import or link in CSS?

Use of @import

```
<style>@import url(Path To stylesheet.css)</style>
```

Use of Link

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Path To stylesheet.css">
```

Answer (score 156, accepted):

In theory, the only difference between them is that `@import` is the CSS mechanism to include a style sheet and `<link>` the HTML mechanism. However, browsers handle them differently, giving `<link>` a clear advantage in terms of performance.

Steve Souders wrote an extensive blog post comparing the impact of both `<link>` and `@import` (and all sorts of combinations of them) called "[don’t use @import](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/09/dont-use-import/)". That title pretty much speaks for itself.

Yahoo! also mentions it as one of their performance best practices (co-authored by Steve Souders): [Choose `<link>` over @import](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#csslink)

Also, using the `<link>` tag allows you to define ["preferred" and alternate stylesheets](https://alistapart.com/article/alternate/). You can't do that with `@import`.

Answer (score 7):

No real difference today, but `@import` is not handled correctly by older browsers (Netscape 4, etc.), so the [`@import` hack](https://web.archive.org/web/20140117190832/http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Import_Hack) can be used to hide CSS 2 rules from these old browsers.

Again, unless you're supporting really old browsers, there isn't a difference.

If I were you, however, I'd use the `<link>` variant on your HTML pages, because it allows you to specify things like media type (print, screen, etc.).

Comment: To specify the media is possible for @import statements too.

Comment: Really? I guess you could put a media type on your style tag, but that seems a bit like a hack to me.

Comment: You can do e.g. "@import url(style.css) screen, print", though IE7 and before don't support the media types.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the import command to import another CSS inside a css file which is not possible with the link command. Really old browser cannot (IE4, IE5 partially) handle the import functionality. Additionally some libraries parsing your xhtml/html could fail in getting the style sheet import. Please be aware that your import should come before all other CSS declarations.

Answer (score 6):

The <link> directive can allow for multiple css be loaded and interpreted asyncronously.

the @import directive forces the browser* to wait until the imported script is loaded inline to the parent script before it can be correctly processed by it's engine, since technically it is just one script.

A lot of css minimization scripts (and languages like less or sass) will automatically concatenate linked scripts into the main script since it ends up causing less transfer overhead.

* (depends on the browser)

Answer (score 1):

When I use the @import rule, it's generally to import a stylesheet within an existing stylesheet (although I dislike doing it to begin with). But to answer your question, no I don't believe there's any difference. Just make sure to put the URL in double quotes in order to comply with valid XHTML.

Answer (score 1):

@import is generally meant to be used in an external stylesheet rather than inline like in your example. If you *really* wanted to hide a stylesheet from very old browsers you could use that as a hack to prevent them from using that stylesheet.

Overall, the `<link>` tag is processed more quickly than the @import rule (which is apparently somewhat slow as far as the css processing engine is concerned).

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Internet Explorer 9 (MSIE9) doesn't seem to handle @import properly.  Observe these entries from my Apache log (IP address hidden but `whois` said it was owned by Microsoft itself): the main HTML linked to screen.css which had

```
@import url("print.css") print;
@import url("speech.css") aural;
```

which I am now about to change to `link` elements in the HTML, because it seems MSIE9 issues two incorrect requests to the server, getting 404 errors I could do without:

```
[ip] - - [21/Dec/2019:05:49:28 +0000] "GET /screen.css HTTP/1.1" 200 2592 "https://ssb22.user.srcf.net/zhimo/"; "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0;  Trident/5.0)" ssb22.user.srcf.net
[ip] - - [21/Dec/2019:05:49:28 +0000] "GET /url(%22print.css%22)%20print HTTP/1.1" 404 7498 "https://ssb22.user.srcf.net/zhimo/"; "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0;  Trident/5.0)" ssb22.user.srcf.net
[ip] - - [21/Dec/2019:05:49:28 +0000] "GET /url(%22speech.css%22)%20aural HTTP/1.1" 404 7498 "https://ssb22.user.srcf.net/zhimo/"; "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0;  Trident/5.0)" ssb22.user.srcf.net
```

There *were* proper requests for these files afterwards, but we can do without this "shoot at server first, parse `url` after" logic.