# Link to CSS file from CSS file

Tags: css

Is it possible call another external CSS file from external CSS file?

Comment: That's why they're called "cascading" :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, like so:

```
@import "relative/path/to/css.css";
```

Comment: I would say that `link` is considered better practice. `@import` does not download the imported files in parallel to everything else, where as `link` does. Use `link` for improved page performance. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478997/import-or-link-for-importing-stylesheets for more.

Comment: Akamike is right. But sometimes `@import` does come in handy.