# @import vs link

Tags: css, import

First I know the title says this is a duplicate question as asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236601/why-import-is-not-advisable-to-link-css), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022695/difference-between-import-and-link-in-css), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478997/import-or-link-for-importing-stylesheets). Everything I read on this topic is over two years old. A lot has changed in that time period so are the same thoughts still advisable?

Here is an example, I use @import inside a stylesheet to bring in my reset CSS and a couple other styles. Should I change that from `@import` to `<link>`? According to this [article](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) I should use link. So I ask other developers, what is truly the best way as to date (August 25, 2011)

Comment: > to date (August 25, 2011)
> asked Aug 26 '11 at 2:13

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between @import and link in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022695/difference-between-import-and-link-in-css)

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Not much if anything has changed in the past year or two, and we're still dealing with a lot of the same browsers from then, so you should not change your practice.

`<link>` is preferred in all cases over `@import`, because the latter blocks parallel downloads, meaning that the browser will wait for the imported file to finish downloading before it starts downloading the rest of the content.

You can see this in great detail here:

http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/09/dont-use-import/

So, while `@import` may be convenient, that's all it offers. If you really want to take advantage of fast loading times, use the minimum number of stylesheets (probably one in most cases), write good CSS with efficient selectors (the usual stuff), minify it, and use a `<link>` tag.

---

This was going to be a comment but it got too long:

Instead of `@import` (I know it *is* very convenient), you should combine the files into one when your site goes live. You shouldn't be tweaking at that point anyways, and there are a number of tools to help minify it. Personally, using PHP, I have a config file where I define all the CSS files that are written to a separate CSS file (the one I will reference in the `<link>` tag), then if the cached version is old (either determined manually or automatically), it combines/minifies them and writes the content to the "cache" file, and returns a timestamp query string to append to the CSS file name to force a fresh download.

If you are using PHP as well, I highly recommend [cssmin](http://code.google.com/p/cssmin/), it can parse stylesheets for `@import` and pull the content into one file, as well as handle all aspects of minification.

Comment: This still shows up as the top hit on google. I wonder if someone could update / confirm this for 2022.

Comment: Condensing all styles into a single file is a bad idea, especially if you rely on popular 3rd-party extensions like Google fonts. It is better to split style files to one which are unlikely to change (font declaration, keyframes, etc.) and to ones that are more prone to adjustment like layout-related styling. If proper caching is applied to permanent styles, you can declare them using @ import. This is also better coupled by javascript fetch() with "force-cache" before/above the style element that contains the @ import pointing to the same fetched url.