# Is there a difference between custom.css and other css files?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

Are there any notable differences between placing all my CSS into `custom.css`, and dividing it up by controller (For example, putting all user-related CSS into user.css, etc)?

Dividing it up is more organized, but one concern I have is that if I have to write '`@import "bootstrap";`' at the top of every css file, my app might load bootstrap seperately for every file, thereby possibly increasing the load time.

Any input would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding css in different files is, as you said, purely for organizational purposes. It has no functionality differences.

However, when you refer to the @import bootstrap implementation, i would suggest against adding that in every css file, for the reason you stated above (because you can miss something or you can link it twice). If you simply add a reference link at the top of your template html page (if you are using one) or at the top of your html pages (if you are not using one), it ensures that bootstrap is loaded once per page (or once per session if its a single page application) so you wont have to worry about missing bootstrap or loading it multiple times unnecessarily.

hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a matter of personal preference. the more you have code, the more difficulty you will have when debugging or going through the file. For me, I usually store them under the root folder in a `Css folder.` and I also like breaking them down and not mixing `my bootstrap files` with my `custom css`but that's just me. 
I also split it using specific values like for example if i have a css for a specific browser, i put it in the folder a folder like `css/firefox/overrider.css`

I think it is just a matter of preference. for the `import`, individual `css`will be better (correct me if I am wrong). It is better explained here: [Import vs Link files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199364/import-vs-link)