# Visual Studio 2013 How To Switch To boostrap.min.js

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, twitter-bootstrap

I have built an ASP.NET 4.5 Web Forms Application utilizing the Bootstrap 3.2 Framework.

I have both:  bootstrap.js  and boostrap.min.js in my project.

Checking the BundleConfig.cs it is not very apparent as to where these 2 are defined.  Every other 3rd party script that I'm using is clearly defined there.

Checking the  references.js  it appears that bootstrap.min.js is referenced there, but not boostrap.js

That being said I would like to find out how I can go about switching from bootstrap.js to the minified version bootstrap.min.js from within Visual Studio.

Comment: See [bundling and minification](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification).  As for `.config` vs `.cs`, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13726956/304683). Hth...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>Checkout the Bundle.config. You can create your own bundles there.</del>

A release build of the application will use the minified versions.

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" />
```

Comment: the Bundle.config are for CSS Scripts.  The BundleConfig.cs are for JS Scripts as I mentioned.

Comment: My bad misread the question. A release build would use the minification.

Comment: would I need to then delete boostrap.js from my project?

Comment: No it will choose either depending on your build/deployment.

Comment: To expand on this answer a bit:  When `debug=false`, all of the CSS files referenced in Bundle.config will be minified into a single CSS file served to the client.  If a minified version of the css file already exists (e.g. `bootstrap.css` and `bootstrap.min.css`), it will include the minified version.  Otherwise, it will minify the single CSS file (e.g. `myfile.css`.) and include that version.

Comment: @BenjaminRay would that include BundleConfig.cs minifying .js  ?

Comment: BundleConfig.cs works differently.  See our previous discussion here:   http://stackoverflow.com/a/29085866/4669143.  When `debug=false`, the script defined in `.Path="<js file>"` is used.  When `debug=true`, the script defined in `.DebugPath="<js file>"` is used.  If `.DebugPath` is not defined, it uses the value in `.Path` in both cases.  The scripts are not minified or bundled together like the CSS files are, so you would have to add your own minified version in `.Path="myscript.min.js"`.