# How to use HTML <link> media attribute in Wordpress with wp_enqueue_style()?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, media-queries

I am loading stylesheets into my wordpress theme using **wp_enqueue_style()**, like this:

```
wp_enqueue_style(
    'custom-stylesheet',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/stylesheets/style.css',
    array(),
    '1.0.0'
);
```

---

My goal is to use **one stylesheet file for each resolution or media query**.


So I found the following solution :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media='screen and (min-width: 140px) and (max-width: 380px)' href="style.css"/>
```

---

At this point, I'll need to use **media** attribute on my <**link**> tag.

**How can I use it in wordpress ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wp_enqueue_style()` accepts `media` as the final argument:

```
wp_enqueue_style(
    'custom-stylesheet',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/stylesheets/style.css',
    array(),
    '1.0.0',
    'screen and (min-width: 140px) and (max-width: 380px)'
);
```

Read more [in the docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/).

Comment: Thanks ! I have found a similar solution but within sass with `@import url(“style.scss”) only screen and (min-width:320px);`. Is there any performance difference between these two alternatives ?

Comment: Yes, doing an `@import` is always going to be slower: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199364/import-vs-link