# Add font-awesome to gulp project correctly

Tags: sass, gulp, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

How can I add and use font awesome in my new gulp-scss-bootstrap project? What is the clean and right way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you not using a CDN?

Comment: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/use-with-node-js

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1 download fontawesome 5

```
npm install --save-dev @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

2 in a SCSS file

```
@import "../../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome";
@import "../../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands";
@import "../../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular";
@import "../../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid";
@import "../../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/v4-shims";
```

3 in gulpfile.js add a task

```
gulp.task('icons', function() {
    return gulp.src('node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dist+'/assets/webfonts/'));
});
```

Comment: Their docs which have a few additional details: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/sass and https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/hosting-font-awesome-yourself  You can for example set a `$fa-font-path` to change the location of the webfonts folder if needed, and use their mixins

Comment: Additionally, the first import of `fontawesome` is required. The imports that follow are for specific styles; new styles are added by the fontawesome team from time to time. I'm not sure how "required" the shims are

Answer (score 3):

Install font awesome using NPM. You can add it to your package.json:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "latest",
    "font-awesome": "latest",
etc
```

Then add a gulp task to copy the files from node_modules to a directory in your deployment:

```
gulp.task('copy', function() {
    gulp.src([
            'node_modules/font-awesome/**',
            '!node_modules/font-awesome/**/*.map',
            '!node_modules/font-awesome/.npmignore',
            '!node_modules/font-awesome/*.txt',
            '!node_modules/font-awesome/*.md',
            '!node_modules/font-awesome/*.json'
        ])
        .pipe(gulp.dest('vendor/font-awesome'))
etc
```

Run `gulp copy` and it should set up the directory for you. Then you can import the font into your index.html

```
<link href="vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: You are suggesting an end-of-life version of FontAwesome.

Comment: I saw the version with @import font awsome in main scss. Is it a good practice too?

Comment: I think `link` in the HTML file is generally preferred over `import` in a CSS file, since the browser will download linked files in parallel for faster page loading. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199364/import-vs-link) answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually:

```
npm install --save-dev @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

fort not font.

[Better to link to directly, as the command may change](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/using-package-managers)

The link may also change, but you can always search it on fontawesome.com

Comment: It's better to not "just" link, as web pages move. It's okay if your command is version-specific. It's always better to give some context for the link, quote the relevant commands, and link to more information. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer