# Does CSS spec explicitly prohibit parallel downloading of several style files when using @import?

Tags: html, css, import

It is commonly said that an `@import` statement shown up in a CSS file will prevent parallel downloading of these CSS files, while defining them through several HTML `<link>`s will not incur such a disaster (just one [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7199377/5006880)).

Is this behavior of `@import` spec-defined or it is just a matter of current browsers implementation? I've only found this relevant statement in the [CSS spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-5/#at-import):

> The `@import` rule allows users to import style rules from other style
> sheets. If an `@import` rule refers to a valid stylesheet, user agents
> must treat the contents of the stylesheet as if they were written in
> place of the `@import` rule ...

It hardly disallows parallel downloads. So is it possible browsers might change over to parallel downloading at some point?

Comment: Have you actually checked that it does block parallel downloads? The source document from stevesouders.com doesn't say that it does, at least not in modern browsers.

Comment: @Alohci Frankly, I haven't. I just came across this statement in a few SO answers and my first reaction was to have a glimpse of the spec. Seemingly, those old answers call for updating.