# Page in Explorer < 8 doesn't get styled for some reason

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, ie7.js

I am setting up a page partly in HTML5 styling in combination with the ie7.js script (which enables html5 styling support). It worked before [flawlessly](http://haendehoch.nl), but now I'm using the same setup, the [website](http://zzappservices.nl/wordpress/) comes up in IE6/7 unstyled. I've been busy with it now for days and cannot find out why. Anyone that is able to find out what's wrong?

This is my head:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE9.js"></script><![endif]--> 

<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://zzappservices.nl/wordpress/wp-content/themes/zzapp/style.css" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="http://zzappservices.nl/wordpress/wp-content/themes/zzapp/favicon.ico" />

<!-- Scripts, CSS and settings specific targeted to Internet Explorer -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://zzappservices.nl/wordpress/wp-content/themes/zzapp/css/ie.css" type="text/css" /><![endif]--> 
<!--[if IE 6]><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://zzappservices.nl/wordpress/wp-content/themes/zzapp/css/ie6.css" type="text/css" /><![endif]--> 

<!--[if IE]>
<link href="http://zzappservices.nl/wordpress/wp-content/themes/zzapp/css/ie.css" media="screen, projection" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<meta http-equiv="Page-Enter" content="progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Fade(Duration=0.0001)">
<meta http-equiv="Page-Exit" content="progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Fade(Duration=0.0001)">
<![endif]-->
```

The page works perfect in webkit/mozilla browsers.

Comment: It seems that it chokes on the declaration in style.css: `@import url('css/layouts/1column.css') all; @import url('css/styling.css') all; @import url('css/print.css') print; @import url('extra.css') all;` if I link those stylesheets directly it works (although layout is pretty f up, but that's what I expected). Anyone has a clue why this happens?

Comment: Anyway, I will ditch the @import method since it apparently affects performance negatively anyway: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801302/css-import-or-link-rel-with-media-attribute. Still wonder why explorer chokes on this though...

Comment: In IE, if @import is used for CSS the stylesheets will be included after the body has loaded so if your JavaScript is relying on a CSS class or style being defined, it may be failing due to that.  Avoiding @import is an excellent idea.

Answer (score 1):

One problem you might be having is due to the fact that your CSS stylesheet that is supposed to be included if IE < 9 is not there.  Try visiting: http://zzappservices.nl/wordpress/wp-content/themes/zzapp/css/ie.css and you'll get a blank page.

It appears the IE 6 stylesheet is also not present.  If allowed, you should be copying these files locally for your site for reliability.

Comment: They are there, but they are empty so far, since I haven't started making the site IE compliant yet. But even if I remove the references, it still happens. It is actually only in IE<8