# Responsive bootstrap-sass setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, bootstrap-sass

I'm trying to use [bootstrap-sass (2.1.0.0)](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass) for a responsively designed Ruby on Rails 3.2.8 site. This is my first attempt at responsive design with Rails or Bootstrap.

The problem is that some, but not all, of my CSS styles are being matched to the appropriate selectors. Specifically, the custom styles that I apply to, say, `.navbar-fixed-top` in custom.css.scss appear both in my compiled custom.css stylesheet and on the page rendered in the browser. However, the responsive Bootstrap styles for `.navbar-fixed-top` *appear in the compiled custom.css (according to Chrome's Inspector) but do **not** appear on the page rendered in the browser*.

If, inside custom.css.scss, I change `@import "bootstrap-responsive";` back to the default `@import "bootstrap";`, the Bootstrap styles for `.navbar-fixed-top` appear on the rendered page. The issue seems to be related to the responsiveness specifically.

I've had trouble finding related info related to my specific issue. I changed the Bootstrap default `meta name="viewport"` tag to `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">` after finding [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386429/simple-bootstrap-page-is-not-responsive-on-the-iphone), but my issue isn't iPhone specific.

I've also been restarting the `$ rails server` while troubleshooting this issue.

I'm at a loss on how to troubleshoot this further. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`bootstrap-responsive` is a supplement to `bootstrap`. Try including them both with `bootstrap-responsive` below `bootstrap`.

```
@import "bootstrap";
@import "bootstrap-responsive";
```

From http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive:

> Turn on responsive CSS in your project by including the proper meta tag and **additional** stylesheet within the  of your document.