# Responsive 2-columns squares in CSS

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design, responsive

I'm trying to create a responsive page with squares taking 50% of full width (2 squares per row). On mobile (including iPhone 6/7 Plus), those squares should be one under the other but that's where it's not working with the following code:

```
.square {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vw;
  float: left;
}

@media (min-width: 1170px) {
  .square {width: 50vw; height: 50vw; }
}
```

Ideally I would use Bootstrap but I can't figure how to create squares.

Comment: Have you set `html, body { margin: 0 }`?

Comment: Yes - I think it's related to the 'device-pixel-ratio' of smartphone which makes the use of width obselete

Comment: No, it's actually based on the fact that viewport units doesn't exclude the scrollbar...posted an answer for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap example:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="square"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="square"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.square {
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

http://codepen.io/Deka87/pen/yMrmKK

Comment: It looks exactly like the answer I'm looking for but squares are not responsive on my code, it's still 2 columns on mobile. Does your Codepen include Bootstrap?

Comment: Ok got it, I was missing a meta tag: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386429/simple-bootstrap-page-is-not-responsive-on-the-iphone

Comment: @Johannes, used in Bootstrap to power responsive embeds too.

Comment: But if there is content, you have to put it in another container on top of it (absolute position), don't you?

Comment: @Johannes, correct, you should add `position:relative;` to the square container and wrap its contents in an absolutely positioned container: `position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/5xc8fs0a/

It leverages the fact that padding percentage is based off of width, so padding-bottom: 100% makes sure the height and width are exactly the same.

```
.square {
  float: left;
  width: 48%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  background: red;
}

.square:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}
```

Comment: It's great but not responsive!

Comment: It's responsive as in it responds to when you change the viewport, its width responds. What do you mean by "not responsive" - that it doesn't stack for smaller views?

Comment: Maybe this is more what you're looking for - with bootstrap loaded in: https://jsfiddle.net/90wzj4t0/