# Responsiveness of Bootstrap page

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Can you say why do this code is not adapt to different mobile devices? I am HTML beginner and can not figure it out. I'm using Bootstrap 4 framework.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=yes">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="xxxxx.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif|Gloria+Hallelujah|Indie+Flower" rel="stylesheet"> 

    <title>xxxxx</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class = "container">
   <hr class = "spec-hr">
  <div class = "row justify-content-md-center">
    <div class = "col-md-6 text-left name">
  xxxxxx
  </div>
  <hr class = "spec-hr">
 </div>
  <div class="row justify-content-md-center intro">
    <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
      Photo
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
      Kontakt<br>
      <p class = "email">xxxxx@gmail.com<br>
      mobile: xxxx<br>
      facebook: xxxxx</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr class = "spec-hr">

  <!--Motto-->

  <div class="row justify-content-md-center motto">
    <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
      <p class="motto">Every day is a chance to get better<br></p>
       <p class = "podpis" >(Lukasz Fabianski, goalkeeper Sweansy City)</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr class = "spec-hr">

  </div>
  </body>

 </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You use classes such as `col-md-6` and `col-md-3`, these are for medium sized screens., for mobiles, you need classes such as `col-6` and `col-3`. See [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options) for examples and definitions

Comment: The page will never be responsive without the correct meta tag! [Read the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#responsive-meta-tag)

Comment: however, if the correct classes arent used, you will never get the correct layout within the grid

Comment: I have to test different options! Can I use something that will make the page flexible??? I mean that will look fine on screan, mobile, ipad, ect

Comment: You don't need to specify `col-*` classes. If you for example use `col-md-*`, the grid will automatically collapse on smaller screens than medium.

Comment: you can use something like `class="col-12 col-md-6"`, this will take up all the width on phones and small tablets, then on larger tablets and computer screens, it will only take up half the width

Comment: @Klooven you do need to specify `col-*` classes else you can encounter weird behavior on smaller screen sizes

Comment: `col-12 col-md-6` is completely same as `col-md-6`

Comment: that was solely an example, the OP may want `col-8 col-md-6`

Comment: The OP doesn't tell. I'm just assuming "responsive" means that the columns collapse on small screens for him.

Comment: responsive could also mean resizing accordingly

Comment: @mast3rd3mon - layout and responsiveness aren't the same thing. In some cases stacking the cols would be the desired responsive layout. As I said, it will never work on mobile devices w/o the correct meta tag.

Comment: @ZimSystem i know they arent the same, and i never said they were

Answer (score 0):

> "Can you say why do this code is not adapt to different mobile
>   devices?"

The meta tag is wrong. It should be:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">`

The page will **never** be responsive without the correct meta tag. [Please **read the documentation**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#responsive-meta-tag)...

> "To ensure proper rendering and touch zooming for all devices, add the
>   responsive viewport meta tag to your `<head>`."

**Also see:**

[Simple Bootstrap page is not responsive on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386429)
[Responsive website zoomed out to full width on mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19156510)

Comment: the issue is that the column classes that are used are wrong for mobile devices, they are all for tablet sized screens

Comment: @mast3rd3mon - The page will **never** be responsive without the correct meta tag! [Read the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#responsive-meta-tag)

Answer (score -1):

For design to be responsive for mobile devices, use bootstrap classes like col-xs-3, col-xs-6. "col-xs-*" is used to target mobile devices having width greater than 230 and less than 768. Also use @media screen {} to target specific style to specific width mobile device.

Comment: `xs` is deprecated in bootstrap 4