# Use custom fonts defined in a separate CSS file

Tags: css, fonts, custom-font

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between @import and link in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022695/difference-between-import-and-link-in-css)

I have a `.css` file which defines all the custom fonts, and I want to reference these fonts in other separate `.css` files for different pages.

What is the right way to do this? `@import` or load both `.css` files for each page?

Comment: id opt for the @import query. You might want to look at LESS anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if @import is a good way:

[Difference between @import and link in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022695/difference-between-import-and-link-in-css)

You should choose the link before the @import for performance.
You might want to take a look at LESS or SASS, like toxicate20 mentioned.

Good luck!