# Difference between <style type="text/css"> & <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />

Tags: css

I'm rather new to this so its mostly (copy and paste) with a little YouTube and reading materials here and there.

Why have both? Please simplify you answer, don't go so technical.

Comment: One is an internal style sheet and the other is external.  Googling that is a good start or searching for the same question elsewhere on stackoverflow rather than posting a new question

Answer (score 11):

`<style type="text/css">` is when you want to have style rules embedded within the page.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/style.css" />` is when you have a separate stylesheet file that you want to reference in the current page - doing this means that clients don't have to download the CSS every time, which makes page-loads faster.

CSS has the `@import` directive, if you use `<style>@import style.css;</style>` then it's roughly equivalent to `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />` (but with some minor differences: see [Difference between @import and link in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022695/difference-between-import-and-link-in-css) ).

Comment: Also, there is no `<link>` alternative to `<style scoped>`. For loading of external css files with that, @import is the only way.

Answer (score 3):

**Method 1** (using `<style type="text/css">`)

Is simple way to declare CSS. But it should be used for small codes. When you want to overwrite an attribute of the main stylesheet.

**Method 2** (using `<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/style.css" />`)

The first advantage of this method is that, we have a style in an external file. And that means that we can use it repeatedly. But this is not the end of the advantages. You can tell your browser to save the file in the cache. Which reduces page load time.

---

**What is better?**

In my opinion **Method 2**.

Answer (score 2):

Using `<style type="text/css">` is for CSS code in your HTML file and `<link...>` is for including an external CSS file.

Answer (score 1):

The first case `<style type="text/css">` is for including css definitions in your html file.  The 2nd case puts the css definintions in style.css (or whatever file is the href).  The 2nd case makes it easy to use the same css across multiple html files.

Comment: In that case shall I just have one of them written instead of both since they fetch the same way?

Comment: Using the external style sheet (your 2nd case) is preferred.  In general it keeps your code better organized.  If I have a class or 2 that is specific to one page, I'll use the 1st option (in additon to the external style sheet that has my site's shared css) to define those styles.  If I have more than that, I'll create a new external style sheet for that page.  It just all depends on how you want to organize your code.

Answer (score 0):

The first is used to insert css code directly in your html files, while the second is calling an external css file.